# Fullscreen Hero issue with dropdown menu when resizing window

Tags: jquery, resize, window

I have created a Fullscreen Hero taking into account the height of my navbar.

```
function fullScreenHero(){
    var width=$(window).width();
    var navHeight=$('nav').height();
    var height=$(window).height()-navHeight;
    $('#hero').width(width);
    $('#hero').height(height);
}
```

For mobile and tablets I added to the navbar a dropdown menu. The problem occurs when the dropdown menu is displayed and then I resize the window. The dropdown menu occupies half of the screen.

**The issue is the hero gets cutted in half when you resize the window because `var navHeight` is double in size when the dropdown is displayed.**

The function below sometimes work, but not always, so it's useless.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('nav').removeClass('dropdown-menu');
});
```

Comment: When I resize with the dropdown visible, the dropdown disappears. Did you fix the issue?

Comment: @arbuthnott sorry, I should have not made changes in the website. I didn't solve the problem, just did a quick fix. I just got rid of  `var navHeight=$('nav').height();` so right now the hero is a slight bigger than the window. The thing is I need to deliver this website to a client today, so I'm going to edit my post and delete the link to the website. Indeed, the dropdown disappears when you resize the window, but **the issue is that the hero gets cutted in half because `var navHeight` is double in size when the dropdown is displayed**